# firebase update does not timeout or error when network is disconnected

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to `update` a document when the network is disconnected:

```
const ref = database.collection("surveys").doc(surveyId);
await ref.update(updates).then(function() {
  console.log("Write completed")
}).catch(function(error:any) {
  console.error("Write failed: "+error)
});
```

I am using the Chrome network tab  to disable the network (Offline)

When the above code is called the `catch` is not invoked - even after waiting a considerable amount of time. Ideally it would be best if it failed immediately (or at least within 5 seconds)

How can you make the `update` call error when the network is down?

Answer (score 0):

By default, firebase has an offline mode, which queues up requests and waits until it goes online again. While I can't found on their documentation how to disable this offline mode, I suggest that you can detect if the connection is lost, then actively show an error message and block the UI:

```js
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");
  } else {
    alert("not connected");
  }
});
```

Comment: this solution doesnt seem to work too well. if you simulate online->offline the last popup you get is 'connected' - i.e. it is incorrectly telling me its online.